# Does SPSite.dispose() and SPWeb.dispose() always needs to be called?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, dispose

I have been debating on this topic for a couple of days. I checked several blogs and did some testing with SPDisposeChecker.exe as well. It seems that there are various ideas about when a Dispose() has to be called. For example this blog by Christian Glessner:

http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/03/sharepoint-disposing-myths.html

Says that it is not necessary to Dispose a web all the time with SPWeb.

However Microsoft best practice recommends to Dispose any Openweb. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx

On the following block of code (which is bit old and is not inside an Using block)::

```
       try
      {

          SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite.aspx");
          web = site.OpenWeb();
          site.Dispose();
          site = null;
      }
      catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException x)
      {
          return;
      }
```

If I do a quick check with SPDisposeCheck it gives an error:

"Disposable type not dispose" on the line where web = site.OpenWeb();

But when I put a finally block like:

```
  finally
      {
        if (web != null)
         web.Dispose();
      }
```

The SPDisposeCheck gives the following error:
"Notes: Dispose should not be called on this object"

Doing a little research I found that SPDispose has some bug on it as explained by this blog

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/3fe362b3-cc03-43e5-a076-bf37dd8175c9

So I remained kind of unsatisfied by my research. I mean off course following Microsoft best practice is good, which recommends to always Dispose(). However I am still not fully satisfied as to when and when not to dispose.

Also "When you dispose the SPSite it loops through all SPWebs in “m_openedWebs” and calls the Close method on each" is this a correct statement?

And back to my code block is a SPWeb.Dispose (on the finally block) really needed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a MCSD for SharePoint  and I do a lot of maintenance programming on SharePoint. I tend to be conservative when it comes to the SharePoint APIs, because I've lived through their evolution and have seen a lot of their growing pains.

My advice to you is that if you open a web (or other SharePoint disposable object), it's in your best interest to dispose of it as soon as you're done with it. Even is cases where SPWebs are automatically disposed of, it may be in your best interest to reclaim the resources of that object. If a site has 1,000 webs, do you want to keep them all open while you iterate through them? Probably not. Obviously, if you're receiving a context object, you should leave those along -- you're not creating them, so they're not really you're responsibility.

[The best practice for SPSite.OpenWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx#sharepointobjmodel__spwebobjects) says "(the SPWeb returned by OpenWeb) is not stored in the SPSite object and is not disposed of anywhere in the SPSite class. For this reason, you should dispose of any object created via these methods. So I'm not sure how it would get added to `m_openedWebs`. So, in regard to your question, "When you dispose the SPSite it loops through all SPWebs in “m_openedWebs” and calls the Close method on each" is this a correct statement?", yes, in a technical sense, it is correct. Can you rely on m_openedWebs to contain every site that you've opened? Probably not. So I would therefore add the finally block and make sure the SPWeb got disposed of correctly.

Comment: So the error message given by SPDisposeCheck.exe is probably wrong as suggested by the blog post I mentioned?

Comment: SPDisposeCheck is a good tool for spotting missed `Dispose` calls. My experience says it's not great at detecting extra `Dispose`s. Looking at your code sample, you explicitly open the site, and then the web. Consider that if your `SPSite` would dispose of the `SPWeb`, the `SPWeb` would be null when you reach the `finally` block. So `if (web != null)` evaluates false nothing happens. If you do get to the finally block and the SPWeb is _not_ null, then it will get disposed. Worst case, you're double checking the SPWeb. Best case, you're saving memory and ensuring proper disposal. Keep it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should not dispose of an SPSite/Web that you didn't create, most notably `SPContext.Current` or the site/web passed to you when running an event handler of a feature.

All of the rest of the time you should be disposing of it, usually using a `using` is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that not all things close and dispose like the documentation guarantees. Case in point: Microsoft JET or ACE Acces will not close connections when using Ole objects.

The following discussion is for items that correctly implement `IDispose`:

- Something I've found is that if I am only going to access a method periodically (once an hour or so), I can wait for the Garbage Collector (GC) to dispose of the item for me.
- If I am making a call that will iterate over a number of items, it seems best to actually call `Dispose()` on the object I have created when I am through with it.

So, I suppose it all comes down to how you use this in your code.

I hope this helps. It isn't much of an answer, though.